# Xamarin app with IdentityServer, how to use the callback url after registration

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin, xamarin.android, blazor, identityserver4

I have a Blazor application that uses an IdentityServer4 instance for authentication. it works perfectly.
But now I try to create the related Xamarin application, so...

About the web app, I have

1. After the login, the app uses the field 'Client.RedirectUri' (From Identity server Client) to redirect to 'https://www.myapp.com/signin-oidc'
2. Once I register, I have a button that redirects to the home page 'https://www.myapp.com'

About the Xamarin app

1. It uses a web view to navigate to the identity server, and the RedirectUri is 'myapp://callback'.
   The mobile app can handle this callback.
2. When registering, it returns to the home page, but it is the "web home page". I should use the 'myapp://callback' instead to allow the Xamarin app to returns to its home page.

So, the problem is that I do not find such a feature for register (only for login & log out)

So, how can I do to force my web app to call the 'myapp://callback' instead of 'https://www.myapp.com' ?

Comment: Please share the code of how you are doing the registration?

Comment: Sire, you should learn to beg, you should learn to thank, and you should learn to up-vote and accept answers that helped you. Personally, I will never answer your questions again.

Comment: @enet sorry, but I do not understand what you are talking about! Once I got a final answer, tried it and it works, then I always 'accept'.